# Web Dev stacks - GONE WILD --- Best Practice Architecture & Deployment?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I've run into a problem that I'm sure many new/junior web developers are facing. Before I state the problem, it's best if I first list the events that drove me to the "issue".

Step 1 - The Front-End:
I followed tutorials which allowed me to create a Vue project using the vue-cli - I now have a nice front-end ready to go, albeit it is in a way "standalone". It sits in its own directory.

Step 2 - The Back-End:
I move on, I start to look at the back-end. Laravel plays well with Vue so I go with it. Once again I follow tutorials, I create a database and an API. Fantastic.

I now have the barebones core elements for a CRUD application. However, the way the back and front end are connected seems to be convoluted (although this may be due to my inexperience and improper understanding).

Solution 1:
Some tutorials insist that the Vue project is "re-created" within the Laravel directories so Laravel is in charge of rendering the views.

Solution 2:
Others, from what I can tell keep them physically separate and have the front-end interact with Laravels API only.

What are the best practices when it comes to stack architecture? Should we aim to bundle the stack together as proposed in solution 1?  Is solution 2 even possible or is that due to my misunderstanding? If it is, how is deployment handled?

Comment: If you have a full Single Page Vue Application you don't need Laravel to render the views and you can get all the data from Laravel API endpoints, so you can keep the projects separate.

Comment: Thanks @thefallen - I realized I missed a point in my question regarding deployment with such "split" solutions. Questions updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of experience, both are correct and the answer depends on what you want to build

First, if you have a simple website and you want to make the front-end of it in vue and it is only this one website, you can put it all together and make the frontend in Vue, which is handled by laravel in the backend and you are done.

Second, the step further, is for this case, that you can have several frontends for your project. Example: You have a website and several (native or universal) apps to display your data. In this case, you can build an API, that handles all the logic, all the business secrets, and this stuff, that no one should know in detail. After that, you are free to build any frontend (Vue, native, plain-HTML), whatever) you like, that's the only purpose is to display the data the API gives back (with some little logic in it, of the cause, but the secret business logic is hidden in the API). You can even outsource the generation of an app, so you build the website frontend in Vue and another one can build an ios-app with swift or an android app with kotlin.

Hope, you get the point, the answer is, as often: it depends

Comment: Thank you @Paladin. Are you able to elaborate in your answer how 'Solution 2' would be packaged for deployment?

Comment: @SheerKahn I can explain you that for the API part, for this is my daily job . I use laravel forge and bitbucket for automatic continous deployment on the master branch for the production server and the development branch for the test server. On forge, there is a deployment script that handles the job after it gets triggered by bitbucket, when a new commit arrived. In general steps: You push something to your vcs (in my case git on bitbucket). Then, you either have a automatic way to deploy your stuff or you just `git pull` you changes and rebuild your laravel configuration on the server. Ez

Comment: Hmmm ok, so do you have the front-end on the same server? Or Front-End on serverA and API/Database on ServerB?

Comment: @SheerKahn Little bit more complex, API on Server A, Frontend on Server F.A to F.x, Databases on Server DB.A to DB.x. Even the API could be on several Server, but we didn't test this yet.This "split-of" between API and Frontend gives you a lot of flexibility, but it's also more work to get to this point.

Comment: Very interesting! Is the segregation of "components" purely for maintainability ? I also see tutorials talking about 'dockerizing' an app for deployment. What are your thoughts regarding this method?

Comment: @SheerKahn This was just a requirement, so we can work on this project with several teams. When it comes to docker, i am out, sry, i do not need this 

Comment: hahaha, fair enough! One final question. If Laravel is purely being used as the back-end. Is there a process regarding configuration to achieve this? I ask because Laravel has its own "Hello world example" view. If something else is handling front-end rendering. Then if you deploy Laravel on its own. What is stopping someone landing on that 'example hello world' page? How do you explicitly tell Laravel you are only using it is an API? - Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @SheerKahn You can configure the routes that are possible to use. So, when there is no front-end view to reach, example /, a user with a browser get's no output ... or you put a landing page to the browsers view, telling, what this is, like we done 

Comment: See that's where more confusion comes from. Vue has it's own vue-router. I guess this comes from not understanding laravel completely. So there is no way to shutoff the 'webserver' component of laravel?

Comment: Sure, simply put no routes to the `routes/web.php` and you are done ... all the routes belongs to `routes/api.php` then and you are good to go  Laravel has no "webserver component" as you suggest, it just answers requests, like all php does .... it is up to you to define, what requests are allowed (and what not)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201884/discussion-between-sheerkahn-and-paladin).